# Javascript DOM Loading an array of images into a div background?

Tags: javascript, image, dom, html, tags

Basically I have images in a folder named `image0.png, image1.png, image(index).png` and I want to load these images (preload so they don't take forever to load after the page loads) into an image tag within a div. The image tag is generated by DOM and then initialized to default parameters. The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the Document model to take the array full of images and just load it into the image tag `IMGTG.src = IMGS[0];`? Heres the code below

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

IMGS = new Array(); 
var IMGTG;

function INIT_IMGTG(id)
{       
    IMGTG = document.createElement("img");      
    IMGTG.setAttribute("height", "100%");
    IMGTG.setAttribute("width", "100%");    
    IMGTG.setAttribute("border", "0");      
} 
function LOAD_IMGS() 
{    
    var index = 0;              

    for(index = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {               
        IMGS[i] = "image" + index + ".png"
    }            
}  
function IMG_ARY(id) 
{
    LOAD_IMGS();    
    INIT_IMGTG(id); 

    IMGTG.src = IMGS[0];        
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload = "IMG_ARY('IMG_ID')">
<div id="IMG_ID"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
I made the edits as described below by the two answerers so far but still no luck? I'm not sure what gives, Javascript is a quirky language.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

IMGS = new Array(); 
var IMGTG;

function INIT_IMGTG(id)
{       
    IMGTG = document.createElement("img");      
    IMGTG.setAttribute("height", "100%");
    IMGTG.setAttribute("width", "100%");    
    IMGTG.setAttribute("border", "0");  
    id.appendChild(IMGTG);
} 
function LOAD_IMGS() 
{    
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {               
        IMGS[i] = "image" + i + ".png";
    }        
}  
function IMG_ARY(id) 
{
    LOAD_IMGS();    
    INIT_IMGTG(id); 

    IMGTG.src = IMGS[0];        
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload = "IMG_ARY('IMG_ID')">
<div id="IMG_ID"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've set the `src` of the image (`IMGTG`) correctly, as well as it's other properties, but you haven't actually inserted it into the DOM.

Try adding this to the bottom of `IMG_ARY`:

```
id.appendChild(IMGTG);
```

Comment: Its actually `document.getElementById(id).appendChild(IMGTG);` Works now thanks!

Comment: Good catch -- I saw you were passing in the id of the container element, and didn't think that it was just a string, not an element reference :)

Comment: Additional information of how to add new elements to HTML page with examples here - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Answer (score 1):

appears to be with the `for` loop where `i` and `index` are interchanged but only `index` has been declared

change

```
var index = 0;              

for(index = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{               
    IMGS[i] = "image" + index + ".png"
}
```

to

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{               
    IMGS[i] = "image" + i + ".png";
}
```

Comment: Its solved now had to use `document.getElementById(id).appendChild(IMGTG);`.